# List of all Google™ app developer ids

Tags: google-play-store, google

[Google Inc](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Google+Inc.) "owns" most of the apps made by Google for Android.

However, there are notable ones that most would consider Google apps, such as

- [Ingress](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticproject.ingress&hl=en) by [Niantic Inc.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Niantic,+Inc.)
- [Sky Map](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.stardroid&hl=en) by [Sky Map Devs](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Sky%20Map%20Devs&hl=en).

Does someone know a list of all the developer ids used for Google-created android apps?

Comment: Hmm... is this on-topic here? It's not about publishing apps yourself, but it feels like it's in a similar train of thought. What's the community say?

Comment: @dotVezz I don't see why it would be off-topic. It's about Android, and of interest to users, and nothing to do with developing apps. The main problem is that it would go out of date whenever Google buys a company with published apps.

Comment: Sounds good to me. You're correct that it'd be hard to keep up-to-date. The list of properties owned by Google is staggering. And it may be difficult to define "what is a Google developer ID?" - one example is probably [Waze](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.waze); do we consider them among NianticLabs@Google and Sky Map Devs, which started as groups within Google - or do we consider it a separate entity, which is merely owned by Google? (TL/DR: Does something like Waze count here?)

Comment: Perhaps the answer could be a community wiki, letting (almost) anyone update it as needed. Besides, there are plenty of questions on this and other stackexchange sites that go out of date; technology is always changing.

Comment: Even more: I don't know about NianticLabs, but I was under the impression that while *Sky Maps Devs* is a group comprised of Googlers, *Sky Maps* is essentially a personal project. That is to say that the app isn't part of their job description, and Google doesn't officially have anything to do with it. (I am probably wrong though...). It seems there could be several categories for the answer here: 1: Official Google-spawned, Google-run ID's. 2: Google-spawned, but not officially Google-run ID's, and 3: Google-owned, but not Google-spawned. (I have terrible wording sense)

Comment: Sky Map was once an official Google App but later released as open source by Google.

Comment: I suppose the solution to this problem would be to go through GOOG's acquisitions for the last few years and find the ones that have an Android app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [Google Inc.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Google+Inc.)
- [Google Creative Lab](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Google+Creative+Lab)
- [Marketing @ Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Marketing+@+Google)
- [Niantic Inc.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Niantic,+Inc.)
  FieldTrip, Ingress, Pokémon GO
- [Waze](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Waze)
  Waze, Waze Rider - Get a Ride
- [Nest Labs, Inc.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Nest+Labs,+Inc.)
  Nest (Learning thermostat), Dropcam (video/security camera)
- [Bitspin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Bitspin) (formerly [Team Tasks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Team%20Tasks))
  Timely, Tasks
- [Bump Technologies, Inc](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Bump+Technologies,+Inc)
  Bump
- [VirusTotal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=VIRUSTOTAL)
  VirusTotal

Comment: For info about acquisition dates and prices, read an updated [List of mergers and acquisitions by Google](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mergers_and_acquisitions_by_Google).